# Can't login to Ubuntu- TTY2 appears on startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a PC which runs on Linux (Ubuntu, and one of the latest versions). When I tried logging in (with the regular log in ID and password), the screen was stuck, and I restarted the PC forcefully. What showed up was a tty2 screen which I can't seem to exit.

I looked up similar problems faced by people, and tried sudo apt-get reinstall ubuntu-desktop, but there were some missing files? I got various "Failed to fetch..." statements when I ran the command. I'm not sure what to do about this.

I'm very new to using Linux, and also to StackExchange.

Comment: Does the tty2 screen give you at least a console login prompt? If you log in and run `journalctl -b -p err` (or maybe scroll through the whole `journalctl -b`), what does it say about "gdm" or "lightdm" (whichever it is that Ubuntu uses)? Does it mention any other failures?

Comment: It's not that you would _exit_ the tty2 screen and return to graphical interface – it's more like the opposite of that; tty1/2/… is always there underneath, and whenever the graphical interface exits (or fails to start) the system returns to tty. So the main task is to go through system logs (journalctl) and figure out why the graphical interface fails to start. (And at the same time, why NetworkManager fails to start or connect to your network.)

Comment: Depending on how much data or customizing has been added, the easiest path might be to reinstall *de novo* from a freshly-made Live Ubuntu USB stick made on Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview) or from a Windows PC (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview). Al;so, rather than try the bleeding edge, you might try a more tested version, such as 20.04 LTS (Long Term Service).